# Perl NET::SSH2 let channel active

Tags: perl, perlnetssh

I need to execute shell script on remote host and wait for it but pipe is broken after 30 minutes. I'm using NET::SSH2.

How can I let the ssh channel active?

I tried:

- `$ssh2->keepalive_config( 1, 2000);` pipe broken, after 30minutes (1800)
- `$ssh2->keepalive_send;`

How can I wait for remote script over this timeout?

Thank you.

Comment: `libssh2` keep alive support is mostly broken. Don't use it!